# How to resolve ffmpeg error cannot load default config file?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have got this error message when using ffmpeg

```
[Parsed_drawtext_0 @ 03bdc300] Could not load font "/Library/Fonts/DroidSansMono.ttf": cannot open resource
Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file
[Parsed_drawtext_0 @ 03bdc300] impossible to init fontconfig
[AVFilterGraph @ 03d9b840] Error initializing filter 'drawtext' with args 'fontsize=15:fontfile=/Lib
rary/Fonts/DroidSansMono.ttf:timecode=00\:00\:00\:00:rate=25:text=TCR\::fontsize=72:fontcolor=white:
boxcolor=0x000000AA:box=1:x=860-text_w/2:y=960'
Error opening filters!
```

Does anyone know how can I resolve this issue?

I'm using ffmpeg on Windows 7. I've downloaded ffmpeg from ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds

This is what I entered and what came up:

```
c:\ffmpeg\bin>ffmpeg -i in.mts -vf "drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/DroidSans.ttf: timec
ode='09\:57\:00\:00': r=25: \x=(w-tw)/2: y=h-(2*lh): fontcolor=white: box=1: boxcolor=0x00000000@1"
-an -y out.avi
ffmpeg version N-70634-g3bedc99 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.9.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzli
b --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libblu
ray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-
libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrw
b --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr -
-enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --
enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enab
le-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enab
le-zlib
  libavutil      54. 20.100 / 54. 20.100
  libavcodec     56. 26.100 / 56. 26.100
  libavformat    56. 25.101 / 56. 25.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 12.100 /  5. 12.100
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, mpegts, from 'in.mts':
  Duration: 00:00:23.42, start: 1.040000, bitrate: 9937 kb/s
  Program 1
    Stream #0:0[0x1011]: Video: h264 (High) (HDMV / 0x564D4448), yuv420p, 1440x1080 [SAR 4:3 DAR 16:
9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x1100]: Audio: ac3 (AC-3 / 0x332D4341), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 256 kb/s
    Stream #0:2[0x1200]: Subtitle: hdmv_pgs_subtitle ([144][0][0][0] / 0x0090), 1920x1080
[Parsed_drawtext_0 @ 02ac2f20] Could not load font "/usr/share/fonts/truetype/DroidSans.ttf": cannot
 open resource
Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file
[Parsed_drawtext_0 @ 02ac2f20] impossible to init fontconfig
[AVFilterGraph @ 03cdb840] Error initializing filter 'drawtext' with args 'fontfile=/usr/share/fonts
/truetype/DroidSans.ttf: timecode=09\:57\:00\:00: r=25: x=(w-tw)/2: y=h-(2*lh): fontcolor=white: box
=1: boxcolor=0x00000000@1'
Error opening filters!

c:\ffmpeg\bin>
```

Comment: Please show the actual command and the complete console output.

Comment: I have entered my info by editing my original question. let me know if I need to include anything else @LordNeckbeard

Comment: You're on Windows, but your path to the font looks like *nix.

Comment: I see. What should the path look like for the windows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it. The error is cuased by the font location in the command is of a Linux computer. The font location need to be different for windows.

The error caused by this line in the command: `drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/DroidSans.ttf`

The above line does not work in Windows.

For windows change to: `drawtext=fontfile=/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf`

Answer (score 2):

Using this drawtext in a program I wrote to embed Created dates into images, I found that you have to escape some characters like colons and backslashes using some versions of FFmpeg with the '`\`' escape character as you did in the timecode sequence. Also enclose paths in single quotes for possible spaces in path or name:

```
drawtext=fontfile='c\\:\\\Windows\\\Fonts\\\Times.ttf'
```

or

```
ffmpeg -i in.mts -vf "drawtext=fontfile='C\\:\\\Windows\\\fonts\\\truetype\\\DroidSans.ttf': timecode='09\\:57\\:00\\:00': r=25: \\x=(w-tw)/2: y=h-(2*lh): fontcolor=white: box=1: boxcolor=0x00000000@1" -an -y out.avi
```

Also some fonts contain multiple `.ttf` files like Times New Roman.  Double clicking this shows Times New Roman Regular, Times New Roman Bold, etc. Times new Roman Regular properties shows its name is `Times.ttf`.  Be sure to use the correct one.

[image: Font Main Folder]

[image: Actual Fonts and Names]